# htaccess dynamic redirect + only if URL begins with value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**i need to make this: site.com/9999100
automatically turn into this: site.com/intro?pn=9999100**

and it should do the same each time someones tries to typing the url with the string 9999 right after the domain name.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this directive to your root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^(9999.*)$ /intro?pn=$1 [R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you so much!
now i see that the joomla .htaccess is blocking me - any ideas on how to workaround?

Comment: can you clarify more the problem you're facing (in another question), and I will try to do my best to help.

Comment: i tried, but no answers there..
i have this: RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
by default at the end of the htaccess, and its blocking my: RewriteRule ^(9999.*)$ /intro?pn=$1 [R=301,QSA]
can you help?